# how to get last 5 week range and its start and end dates in php/ laravel

Tags: php, laravel, date, datetime, php-carbon

I want week range start and end dates last 5 with current week range like follows

```
2019-12-09 : 2019-12-15
2019-12-16 : 2019-12-22
2019-12-23 : 2019-12-29
2019-12-30 : 2020-01-05
2020-01-06 : 2020-01-12
2020-01-13 : 2020-01-19
```

I have able to get current week range's start and end date(2020-01-13 : 2020-01-19) from following code

**In controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $currentWeekNumber = date("W"); 
    $currentYear = date("Y");  
    $weekArray = $this->getStartAndEndDate($currentWeekNumber,$currentYear);
    return view('mainMenu.timesheetFillLanding', compact('weekArray'));
}

public function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) 
{
    //Below gives week from mon to sun
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
    $ret['start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
    $dto->modify('+6 days');
    $ret['end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
    return $ret;
}
```

**On view**

```
{{$weekArray['start']}} : {{$weekArray['end']}}
```

I am not able to get previous week range and its start and end dates. I searched a lot for solutions but not helped.

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: No idea about in laravel but in PHP store value in array like $weekArray[] and in view side use foreach or for loop you get all the value.

Comment: Well then you are going to have to call the function the get the ranges more than once. A loop!!

Comment: Should the start date for the week always be a Monday

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes loop. But don't know how? on which inputs and condition should I check. And week start from monday only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code. It's working for you.
I have changed the `getStartAndEndDate()` function.

```
public function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) 
{
    //Below gives week from mon to sun
    $weeks = [];
    $dto = new DateTime();
    $dto->setISODate($year, $week);    
    for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++) {               
        $weeks[$i]['start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');        
        $dto->modify('+6 days');        
        $weeks[$i]['end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');        
        $dto->modify('-13 days');   
    }
    return array_reverse($weeks);
}
```

## => OUTPUT

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-12-09
            [end] => 2019-12-15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-12-16
            [end] => 2019-12-22
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-12-23
            [end] => 2019-12-29
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2019-12-30
            [end] => 2020-01-05
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2020-01-06
            [end] => 2020-01-12
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [start] => 2020-01-13
            [end] => 2020-01-19
        )

)
```

Comment: Suggestion: Change `return $weeks;` to `return array_reverse($weeks);` and the array will be in the order that the OP asked for in the question :)